# how to update the TTL in C programming?

Tags: c, linux, networking

I'm adding a new function in ping by C.
I want to set the TTL by command line, but the ping is built by ICMP, and TTL is set in IP.
So can you tell me some ways to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: What is TTL? Transistor-Transistor Logic?

Comment: @RobertHarvey in this context I'd wager it means time to live.

Comment: Can I close this question just for its sheer irritation factor?

Comment: @RobertHarvey what exactly is your problem here? I realize the question isn't properly formatted and the wording is a bit difficult to understand, but there's really no need to be so rude about it.

Comment: If you're on Linux-based system and you have the `ping` tool installed, you can simply use the `-t` argument to change the time-to-live. e.g. `ping -t 10 -c 1 <host-addr>` produces a single ping probe with a TTL of 10. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: i just want to add it by myself, for i'm a student so i need more coding. thank you

Comment: If I wanted to learn how to do something that is already done by several open source implementations, I'd start by reading their source.  [Here is one version](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/part4/chap18/ping.c).  Looking for how that implementation handles the `-t` parameter is a good jumping off point.

Comment: thank you ,it implement  by setsockopt().

Comment: please post a response to your question below with your correct answer.  Then wait two days and accept the answer that worked.

Comment: Your question is a contradiction in terms. Either you want to set the TTL via the command line or you want to set it in your program. Or you want to set it via a command line in your program? I can't make any sense of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't mention your target platform (or why you have to reinvent the wheel, as has been mentioned) but regardless here we go.

On *NIX it's a standard socket option to your already open socket. It's just at a different level of the networking stack. Soooo...

```
setsockopt (socket_descriptor, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, val, val_var_len);
```

See W. Richard Stevens for his bible on sockets if you're in a *NIX world. Otherwise, someone else will/might help out.